# Forecasting using exogenous variables in ARIMAX in python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, forecasting, arima

I am trying to forecast a variable called yield spread - "yieldsp"  using several macroeconomic variables. "yieldsp" is a column in a dataframe called "stat2" with date datetime index. Initially, I had forecasted "yieldsp" using the ARIMA model wherein I employed the following code:

```
# fit the model on the train set and generate prediction for each element on the test set.
# perform a rolling forecast : re-create the ARIMA forecast when each new observation is received. 
# forecast(): performs a one-step forecast from the model
# history - list created to track all the observations seeded with the training set
# => after each iteration, all new observations are appended to the list "history",

yieldsp = stat2["yieldsp"]

X = yieldsp.values
size = int(len(X) * 0.95)
train, test = X[0:size], X[size:len(X)]
history = [x for x in train]
predictions = list()

# walk-forward validation
for t in range(len(test)):
    model = ARIMA(history, order=(1,0,4))
    model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
    output = model_fit.forecast()
    yhat = output[0]
    predictions.append(yhat)
    obs = test[t]
    history.append(obs)
    print('predicted=%f, expected=%f' % (yhat, obs))
```

It worked and generated predicted and expected values. A part of the results are shown below:

```
predicted=0.996081, expected=0.960000
predicted=0.959644, expected=0.940000
predicted=0.937272, expected=0.930000
predicted=0.932651, expected=0.970000
predicted=0.976372, expected=0.960000
predicted=0.961283, expected=0.940000
```

But now, I want to use multiplied variables to forecast yieldsp. These variables in "stat2" are:

```
yieldsp = stat2[['ffr', 'house_st_change','rwage', 'epop_diff2','ipi_change_diff2', 'sahm_diff2']]


     ffr        house_st_change   rwage   epop_diff2  ipi_change_diff2     sahm_diff2    yieldsp
Date                            
1982-03-31  14.68   -28.713629  0.081837    -4.000000e-01   -3.614082   0.227545    0.19
1982-04-30  14.94   -32.573529  0.081789    2.000000e-01    0.838893    -0.061298   0.72
1982-05-31  14.45   -10.087719  0.081752    2.000000e-01    -0.765399   -0.062888   1.74
1982-06-30  14.15   -13.684211  0.080928    -2.000000e-01   0.421589    -0.039439   1.08
1982-07-31  12.59   12.007685   0.081026    -1.421085e-14   -0.141606   -0.032772   3.11
```

So, I attempted the following:

```
yieldsp = stat2[['ffr', 'house_st_change','rwage', 'epop_diff2','ipi_change_diff2', 'sahm_diff2', 'yieldsp']]

X = yielsp.values
size = int(len(X) * 0.8)
train, test = X[0:size], X[size:len(X)]
history = [x for x in train]
predictions = list()

# walk-forward validation
for t in range(len(test)):
    model = ARIMA(history, order=(1,0,1))
    model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
    output = model_fit.forecast()
    yhat = output[0]
    predictions.append(yhat)
    obs = test[t]
    history.append(obs)
    print('predicted=%f, expected=%f' % (yhat, obs))
```

But error occurred:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (7) into shape (1)
```

I am unsure how to fix that. I think to forecast "yieldsp" we would need the forecasted values of the exogenous variables too. And I also think we need to modify the codes which state:

```
history = [x for x in train]
predictions = list()

# walk-forward validation
for t in range(len(test)):
    model = ARIMA(history, order=(1,0,4))
```

I would appreciate any kind of help.

(Reference: https://machinelearningmastery.com/make-sample-forecasts-arima-python/)

Comment: I am not sure but probably you can check the following library which deals with ARIMAX: https://pyflux.readthedocs.io/en/latest/arimax.html

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues here:

1. How to we pass exogenous variables to ARIMAX
2. How do we forecast without exogenous variables (out of sample forecast)

For using exogenous variables with ARIMAX

```
yieldsp = stat2["yieldsp"] 
exog_data = stat2[['ffr', 'house_st_change','rwage', 'epop_diff2','ipi_change_diff2', 'sahm_diff2', 'yieldsp']]
# you can process your data here for train and test split 

model = ARIMA(yieldsp, exog=exog_data, order=(1,0,1))
model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
```

For the second problem, ARIMAX/SARIMAX need to have exogenous data for future forecasting otherwise they can't be used.